# Xamarin DisplayAlert no aparece

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async

Hola amigos hice una pequeña clase para manejar mis conexiones con **CrossConnectivity** , pero lo que quiero hacer es una clase a la que pueda llamar en cualquier momento para confirmar mi conexion y que me diga si  no estoy contectado, todo bien pero! cuando llamo a mi Displayalert no aparece, alguien sabe porque? esto es lo que tengo:

```
 public class ConetctivityManager
{
    public static bool CheckConnectivity()
    {
        bool conn  = CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
        return conn;
    }

    public static async Task ConnectivityAlert() {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error de conexion",
            "Asegurece de estar conectado a wifi o activar los datos"+
            " moviles para el correcto uso de esta aplicacion",
            "ok");
    }
}
```

Asi es como la estoy llamando:

```
 public LoginPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        #region connectivity
        var conn = ConetctivityManager.CheckConnectivity();
        #endregion

        if (!conn)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { await ConetctivityManager.ConnectivityAlert(); });
        }


        BindingContext = new LogsViewModel();
     }
```

Comment: Proba, No usar  await con display alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CREO que esto se debe a que lo estás llamando a través de un `Task`, si es completamente necesario mantenerlo intenta anidar el `DisplayAlert` para que se ejecute en el hilo principal, ya que al usar `Task` lo estás haciendo correr en un hilo aparte.

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
    { 
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error de conexion",
            "Asegurece de estar conectado a wifi o activar los datos"+
            " moviles para el correcto uso de esta aplicacion",
        "ok");
    }
);
```

Con eso debería funcionar, por otro lado, tu método YA ES async, no necesitas el Task.Run, por lo que puedes cambiar esto:

```
if (!conn)
{
    Task.Run(async () => { await ConetctivityManager.ConnectivityAlert(); });
}
```

Por esto:

```
if (!conn)
{
    await ConetctivityManager.ConnectivityAlert(); 
}
```

Y así no necesitarías anidar el método con `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` y debiera funcionar en asíncrono de todos modos.

Answer (score 0):

Te reduje el codigo y saque los `await` y `Task`, con el display alert te complican la vida.

```
public class ConetctivityManager
{ 
  public static bool CheckConnectivity()
  {
    return CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected;
  }

  public static ConnectivityAlert() 
  {
    App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error de conexion",
        "Asegurece de estar conectado a wifi o activar los datos"+
        " moviles para el correcto uso de esta aplicacion",
        "ok");
  }
}

public LoginPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    if (!ConetctivityManager.CheckConnectivity())
    {
        ConetctivityManager.ConnectivityAlert();
    }
    BindingContext = new LogsViewModel();
 }
```